# Native Mobile Apps vs HTML5 Effect on Battery

Tags: html, performance, mobile

I recently got into an interesting debate on native applications vs html5 applications, specifically about performance and battery usage. Disclaimer: I tend to favor HTML.

The other person made the argument that native will always be better on battery because the mobile browser has to parse the dom, css, and javascript. I would tend to agree that JS - even well written JS - can be murder on a mobile battery. But I'm not so sure about dom parsing.

So let's take that part out of the equation - I prefer to take a document, not app based approach, e.g. a web "site" vs a web "application." Take a really simple type of site - a blog. This blog just has bootstrap.css and no javascript. Would a native mobile blog application be better on the battery than chrome?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read [this article](http://radar.oreilly.com/2013/05/measuring-the-impact-of-web-page-structures-on-battery-usage-in-mobile-devices.html) on o'reilly regarding battery life vs. computation.

> Would a native mobile blog application be better on the battery than chrome?

That depends entirely what you want to achieve. A 'bare' application is generally faster and less demanding that a feature rich application.